# How could I get all of the sums of my program on the same line?

Tags: c++, io

I'm trying to get all of my outputs to print on one line, at the end of the program. How can I make that happen? Currently, the sum is printed directly after the variables are inputted, looking something like this:

```
3
100 8
108
15 245
260
1945 54
1999
```

I want it to look like this:

```
3
100 8
15 245
1945 54

108 260 1999
```

This is my code currently:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int pairs = 0;
    cin >> pairs;

    for (int i=0,num1=0,num2=0; i < pairs; i++)
    {
        cin >> num1 >> num2;
        cout << num1 + num2 << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work for you in this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, it was unclear what you're asking, but I got you. You're doing your input and output in the same loop. You'll need to have an input and an output loop and a container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    int pairs = 0;
    cin >> pairs;
    std::vector<int> sums; // vector to hold sums, your int sum was unused
    sums.reserve(pairs);

    for(int i = 0; i < pairs; ++i)
    {
        // better initialize these variables here, otherwise they might
        // equal to previous input if this input fails
        // (you should declare them in inner-most scope possible anyway)
        int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
        cin >> num1 >> num2;
        sums.push_back(num1 + num2); // do not cout, append the value to the sums instead
    }

    for(auto x : sums)
        cout << x << " "; // finally print the whole vector
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of providing a convenient alternative: you can send the output to a `std::ostringstream` variable until you want to use it...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int pairs;
    if (std::cin >> pairs)
    {
       std::ostringstream saved_out;

       for (int i = 0; i < pairs; ++i)
       {
           int num1, num2;
           if (std::cin >> num1 >> num2)
               saved_out << num1 + num2 << " ";
           else
           {
               std::cerr << "ERROR: less inputs than promised\n";
               exit(1);
           }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "unable to parse pairs counter from stdin\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << saved_out.str() << '\n';
}
```

I've also made the input checking a little more robust/verbose.